# Can't Import Boto3 into Project

Tags: python, pycharm, boto3

I am trying to setup a project in Pycharm so I can write Python scripts using boto3.

For some reason I can't import boto3 into my project environments.  Anytime I tried to `import boto3` I get `no module name 'boto3'`

I have installed boto3 using Brew, but it doesn't show up.  I am pretty new to setting up environments, so I am note sure if I am doing something wrong.

There are a bunch of options in the 'Base Interpreter" dropdown, I have tried everyone and get the same thing.

Comment: In the console, type 
"pip freeze",  then check for boto3 in the list

Comment: In general I'd recommend using a separate virtual environment to your projects, provide a setup.cfg/setup.py to declare the dependencies, and pip install them into that virtual environment. This is a lot easier to manage with then using the system packages, because there might be conflicting requirements between your projects.